# Pipe to compressed file but also print content to terminal

Tags: bash, compression, pipe, stdout

How do I maintain a readable output from my program while also putting that same output into a compressed file, gzip or otherwise, so I can parse it later?

I run a command that generates a lot of samey lines of clear text that should be easy to compress, but I also want to monitor the output of that command. I know I can use `tee` to print and then put stdin into a file. But the files are massive (250MB+). I also know that I can use `gzip` to compress stdin into a file, but then I won't see any output on the screen and gzip's `--stdout` flag just dumps the compressed data to stdout, which is not what I want.

An example would be

```bash
python -c 'for i in range(0, 100): print("A" * 120)' | gzip --best > A.log.gz
```

but I also want to see the `A`s printed to the console.

Comment: Can you explain why the combination of tee and gzip isn't what you need? Ideally, give us a specific, simple and reproducible example so we can use that to test our approaches.

Comment: Maybe something like `seq 1 100 | tee >(gzip >foo.gz)`

Comment: It sounds like you need either `tee` with a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#index-process-substitution) for the `gzip` command, or [pee](https://man.archlinux.org/man/pee.1). See also [`tee` for commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/371699/tee-for-commands)

Comment: Is this a command/script that creates a lot of output in a single run and terminates or is it a long-running service?

Comment: @Bodo that worked. If you provide an answer I'll accept it. It'd be nice if you included how I could've figured that out myself. This `>(program)` syntax is new to me.

Comment: @terdon tee writes to a file but doesn't compress, gzip compresses but doesn't print. I don't know to "combine" the two as you suggest

Comment: @steeldriver so I can use `>(process)` in place of any file name and the data that would be written to that file would appear as stdin to that process instead? Thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of process substitution, I just wanted an example command to be able to test and be sure it does what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by combining `tee` and [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html):

```
python -c 'for i in range(0, 100): print("A" * 120)' | 
  tee >( gzip > compressed.gz)
```

The `>()` construct, which is one kind of process substitution, allows you to treat a command as though it were a file. In this case, a file opened for writing (`<()` would open for reading). The command above will both print to standard output (since that is what `tee` does by default) *and* redirect to the special "file" `gzip > compressed.gz` meaning it will print to it, thereby passing all output through `gzip` and finally to the compressed file `compressed.gz`.